# Add page into existing PDF document using C# and iTextSharp

Tags: c#, itext

```
int iNbFichier = 0;
while (File.Exists(folderName + "/" + newFile + ((iNbFichier > 0) ? "_" + iNbFichier.ToString() : "") + ext))
{
    iNbFichier++;
}

// open the reader
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(oldFile);
document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 5, 5, 120, 60);

// open the writer
FileStream fs = new FileStream(folderName + "/" + newFile + ((iNbFichier > 0) ? "_" + iNbFichier.ToString() : "") + ext, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fs);
document.Open();

int numberPage = reader.NumberOfPages;                            

// the pdf content
PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;

for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
{
      // create the new page and add it to the pdf
      PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, i);
      cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0);
      if(i != numberPage) document.NewPage();
      cb = writer.DirectContent;
}

if (availableSpace < 90)
{
      writer.NewPage();
      cb = writer.DirectContent;
}                            

// select the font properties
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
cb.SetColorFill(BaseColor.BLACK);
cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 8);

// write the text in the pdf content
cb.BeginText();
string text = "Le " + DateTime.Now.ToString().Substring(0, 10);
// put the alignment and coordinates here
cb.ShowTextAligned(1, text, 455, 750, 90);
cb.EndText();

// write the text in the pdf content
cb.BeginText();
text = salarie.NOM + " " + salarie.PRENOM;
// put the alignment and coordinates here
cb.ShowTextAligned(1, text, 465, 750, 90);
cb.EndText();

// write the text in the pdf content
cb.BeginText();
text = "Signature :";
// put the alignment and coordinates here
cb.ShowTextAligned(1, text, 475, 750, 90);
cb.EndText();

iTextSharp.text.Image img = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(globale.EncodePhoto(this.signature));
//img.SetAbsolutePosition(485, 750);

img.Border = 0;

//Resize picture to fit 380x150 ratio if its bigger
int intMaxWidth = 100;
int intMaxHeight = 50;
BitmapImage bmpMain = this.signature;
if (bmpMain.Height > intMaxHeight || bmpMain.Width > intMaxWidth)
{
      double dblHeightRatio = Convert.ToDouble(intMaxHeight) / Convert.ToDouble(bmpMain.Height);
      double dblWidthRatio = Convert.ToDouble(intMaxWidth) / Convert.ToDouble(bmpMain.Width);
      double dblScaleRatio;

      //Use the smaller ratio
      if (dblHeightRatio > dblWidthRatio)
      {
            dblScaleRatio = dblWidthRatio;
      }
      else
      {
            dblScaleRatio = dblHeightRatio;
      }

      int intNewHeight = Convert.ToInt32(bmpMain.Height * dblScaleRatio);
      int intNewWidth = Convert.ToInt32(bmpMain.Width * dblScaleRatio);

      img.ScaleAbsolute((float)intNewWidth,
                                                    (float)intNewHeight);
}

img.SetAbsolutePosition(480, 700);
img.RotationDegrees = 90;

cb.AddImage(img);                            

// close the streams and voilá the file should be changed :)
document.Close();
fs.Close();
writer.Close();
reader.Close();
```

If the available space into my table and footer is < to 90 then I want to create a new page and put the signature on the last page which is created.

But my code don't works. Someone can help me to solve this ?

My application is for tablet so the duplicate treatment take too much resources to be used in this case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert page into existing PDF using itextsharp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6657899/insert-page-into-existing-pdf-using-itextsharp)

Comment: I've already tried this but it's not work too

Comment: Does it throw an exception?

Comment: I haven't an exception but there isn't page created

Comment: Is the content added, just on the wrong page or is it not added at all? Can you post the old file and the new file so we can compare them?

Answer (score 0):

```
string oldFile = "Tmp.pdf";
string newFile = nomFichier = DateTime.Now.ToString().
                              Substring(0,10).Replace('/','-') + 
                              "_" + salarie.NOM + "_" + salarie.PRENOM;
string ext = ".pdf";
string folderName = "FICHE_EPI";

//Si le tableau est trop bas pour faire passer la signature
if (availableSpace < 90) 
{
    var tempFileLocation = @"Tmp2.pdf";
    var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"Tmp.pdf");

    using (var reader1 = new PdfReader(bytes))
    {
        var numberofPages = reader1.NumberOfPages;
        var pages = 1;

        if (pages != 0)
        {
            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(
                   tempFileLocation, 
                   FileMode.Create, 
                   FileAccess.Write))
            {
                using (var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader1, fileStream))
                {                                            
                    var rectangle = reader1.GetPageSize(1);
                    for (var i = 1; i <= pages; i++)
                        stamper.InsertPage(numberofPages + i, rectangle);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    File.Delete(@"Tmp.pdf");
    File.Move(tempFileLocation, @"Tmp.pdf");
```

This solve my problems.